# Convert network folder to USB drive

Tags: networking, samba, nfs

I know that the question sound creasy, but I will explain the purpose in a while.

I have a NAS at home with many storage space, shared as SMB/NFS folders in my network.

My idea would be to connect 1 of this shared folders with a raspberry and convert it in to a (pretending)USB drive.

Why that?

I have a PS5 and I need an external drive to install the PS4 games. Then I had this idea: Why buy another USB drive when I have 12TB in my NAS? Maybe a Raspberry can "pretend" to be a USB drive and convert the SMB/NFS shared folder to a look-like USB Drive.

Is that possible at all?? Is yes, how you would do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be very complicated, a usb drive is a sector based device, while a network folder exists in the filesystem world. You would need to virtualize a block device based on the network. And also forget about concurrent access, with the caching done on block devices by the OS, it won't work

Comment: In some cases I saw that by using the iSCSI is better. Right?

Comment: I found the following resource for doing this with an local file: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive I don't have a raspberry pi zero to test & expand this resource for using a remote file, but it should be as easy as mounting the network file system and pointing it to a file on that file system